# Filter the elements of an xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? xmlns:xn="whatever.xsd>
    <rootNode>
        <fileHeader />
        <xn:child1>
            <xn:child2 id="1">
                ....
            </xn:child2>
            <xn:child2 id="2">
                ....
            </xn:child2>
            <xn:child2 id="3">
                ....
            </xn:child2>
                ....
        </xn:child1>
</rootNode>
```

And I want to get an output xml filtered depending on the id attribute of the child2 tag. For that, I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd">
    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- override the above template for certain MeContext elements; output nothing. -->
    <xsl:template match="xn:child1[not(xn:child2/@id != '1') and not(xn:child2/@id != '3')]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, the output should be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? xmlns:xn="whatever.xsd>
    <rootNode>
        <fileHeader />
        <xn:child1>
            <xn:child2 id="1">
                ....
            </xn:child2>
            <xn:child2 id="3">
                ....
            </xn:child2>
                ....
        </xn:child1>
</rootNode>
```

But I am not able to get it, what's wrong with my xslt?

EDIT: Updating the xslt because it had a typo

Comment: What is needed to be filtered against id attribute of the child2 tag? The tag itself? Or the parent?

Comment: I need to filter the child2 tags, as it is described in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<xsl:template match="xn:child[not(xn:child2/@id != '1') and not(xn:child2/@id != '3')]">
```

matches an element named `xn:child`. There is no such element in your XML. Perhaps you meant:

```
<xsl:template match="xn:child2[@id != '1' and @id != '3']"/>
```

--
**Note**: a namespace declaration cannot appear in the XML declaration. In addition, if you want your prefix to match nodes in a given namespace, you must bind it to the same namespace URI as the one used by the XML input (the prefix itself can be anything).